# Using separate filters for seperate servlet requests; prevent filter being invoked by a forward on the servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I want to use 2 filters for 2 seperate servlets. The 1st filter is for 1st servlet: `foodtypeServlet` and the 2nd filter is for 2nd servlet: `menuServlet`. In 2nd filter, when there is error, I want to forward to `foodtypeServlet`. But the problem is, when I forward to `foodtypeServlet`, then the filter this servlet get executed as well. I don't want it to get executed. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** the default behaviour assuming that the filters are mapped as follows:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>foodtypeFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>foodtypeServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>menuFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>menuServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Filters are by default only invoked on `REQUEST` dispatcher, not on `FORWARD`, `INCLUDE` nor `ERROR`. For that you'd have to explicitly specify the `<dispatcher>` entries in filter mapping.

Perhaps you're using Servlet 2.3? In that ancient version any filter is indeed by default invoked on a forward as well. You'd need to upgrade to at least Servlet 2.4, or to let the filter check for the presence of the `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri` attribute and if so, then bypass the filter call by just calling `chain.doFilter(request, response)`.

Or perhaps you're *actually* redirecting instead of forwarding? In that case, you should perform a real [forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) instead of [redirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).